# How to set a "bold" dynamic font type for UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

The [Apple documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically?language=objc) that for iOS an app can use text styles and dynamic font type so text size automatically adjusts to the users reading preferences.

I have a text style `Body` and set `Dynamic Type` to `true` so that it automatically adjust the text size. This works good.

This text I would also like to make appear `bold`. I haven't found a way yet how to achieve this either by code or in the Interface Builder.

Is there a way to achieve a "bold dynamic font type"?

Comment: You can not mark **bold** to `Body`, it is a Text Style. Use a System/Custom font to select  **Bold** *Italic* etc.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk thanks for the comment. It seems you pointed me in the right direction to think a bold font could be considered as a "custom font" in my case. The documentation shows how to handle custom fonts. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically?language=objc) provides a hint. For using custom fonts, I consider a `bold` font as a custom font now, one can use the `UIFontMetrics` class.

If I pass a "bold custom font" to the [`scaledFontForFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics/2877385-scaledfontforfont?language=objc) method of `UIFontMetrics` class I get the desired result with the dynamic font type `UIFontTextStyleBody`.

```
UIFont* boldSystemFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
myLabel.font           = [[UIFontMetrics metricsForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody] scaledFontForFont:boldSystemFont];
```

So far I only see this way using code. No idea if this could somehow be setup in the Interface Builder as well.